# Fragment's onCreateView() causes my app to crash

Tags: android, fragment

I'm having a strange problem. I'm using Fragments in an app that has a host FragmentActivity in which I implemented an internal `class FragmentPagerAdapater` that constructs the Fragments and puts them into my activity's tabs.

In the app, I need to pass on an Object from my Activity to the Fragments. I'm not really sure what the proper way to do this is, so I improvised, and went for a static Fragment `newInstance(Object obj)` in my Fragments. This method just calls the default Fragment's constructor and sets a instance variable to hold the Object within the Fragment.

Now in the Fragment's `createView()` method, I use the instance's Object informations to fill the layout. This works fine when the app launches, but the app crashes when I change the screen orientation from portrait to landscape (or the opposite). The logs indicates a NullPointerException on the instance Object in `createView()`. I feel like I missed something in the lifecycle but I can't find the answer. Is there somethign special to do so my Fragments will save their instance variable no matter what ?

Here's a code sample to help you understand what the issue is:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private Object obj;

public static MyFragment newInstance(Object obj) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setObject(obj);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);
    MyType res = ((Type) (obj)).getSomething(); // This line causes the crash because obj is null when I switch to another orientation

    // I Do something with res to fill rootView

    return rootView;
}

private void setObject(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}
}


// In the Activity I simply create the Fragment using
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(myObjectToPass);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: crash => post stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the orientation switches (really whenever Android decides to recreate the `Fragment`), the existing `Fragment` is destroyed then recreated.

However, when Android recreates your `Fragment`, it doesn't call your custom `newInstance()` method. It uses the empty no-args constructor.

This means that your `Fragment` *won't* have a non-null reference to whatever custom `Object` you want, resulting in the NPE being thrown.

You will need to figure out a way to pass the `Object`. If the `Object` is a simple data `Object` consider passing its fields via the `setArguments()` method or Serializing it.

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString ("key_string", "your string here");
fragment.setArguments (data);
```

You could also create an `interface` that queries the Activity for the Object. For example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  public interface ObjectProvider
  {
    public CustomObject getCustomObject();
  }

  private ObjectProvider provider;

  @Override
  public void onAttach (Activity activity)
  {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
      provider = (ObjectProvider) activity;//get an instance of the ObjectProvider
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException ("This isn't an ObjectProvider.");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);

    provider.getCustomObject().getSomething(); 

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Then your Activity needs to implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity implements MyFragment.ObjectProvider{

 @Override
 public CustomObject getCustomObject()
 {
   return new CustomObject();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use setRetainInstance(true) as the following:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Object obj) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setObject(obj);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    return fragment;
}
```

This will persist your object across orientation changes, just make sure the object does not have a reference to a activity context or you will have a memory leak.